# NodeJS SocketIO Multiple Emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I haven't been using socket.io for very long, so I'm still getting accustomed to it.

My issue is that the server emits a message multiple times. I'm not sure; but I believe this is because the client has connected multiple times.

I've tried plenty of solutions, and none of them seem to work. I've placed a snippet of the code.

Server.js

```
var param = req.param.id; 
var snakeIO = io.of('/snake/'+param);
snakeIO.on('connection', (socket) => {
   socket.on('message', (name, message) => {
     name = req.session.username;
     snakeIO.emit('message', name, message);
   });
});
```

Client.js

```
var snakeIO = io('/snake/'+window.location.pathname.split("/")[2], { forceNew: true });
snakeIO.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to snake IO.');
});
snakeIO.on('message', (name, msg) => {
    messages = document.getElementById('messages');
    message = document.createElement('div');
    message.classList.add('list-group-item');
    message.classList.add('bg-dark');
    message.innerHTML = "<b>" + name + "</b> - " + msg;
    messages.appendChild(message);
});
function sendMessage(){
    message =  document.getElementById('sendMessage');
    snakeIO.emit('message', 'U/A', message.value);
    message.value = "";
}
```

Note:

If I add `console.log(socket.id)` to server.js then it reports

```
 /snake/1#WoESDodIxDq2qVDyAAAZ
 /snake/1#WoESDodIxDq2qVDyAAAZ
 /snake/1#WoESDodIxDq2qVDyAAAZ
 /snake/1#...
```

The event multiplies by the amount of duplicates.

Comment: in your server you have `snakeIO.emit('message', name, message);` are you sure you didn't want to just broadcast instead? `socket.broadcast.emit('message', name, message);`

Comment: For the love of god I can't get socket.broadcast.emit to work. I just tried socket.broadcast.emit again and it didn't work. Would it be compatible with the client side code that I currently have running?

Comment: so broadcast emits to all BUT the socket that sent the request. You would probably have to open 2 instances of your app to see broadcast work

Comment: Thanks, I got that working however its still sending multiple messages from the server to each client.

Comment: Usually, the receiving of multiple messages is caused because your have put some event listener inside a route that gets called more than once and thus you end up with duplicate event listeners. This causes your code to execute more than once, either making it seem like you receive multiple messages when in reality, you just have duplicate listeners for the message or duplicate listeners on the sending side that cause you to run the sending code multiple times. To help you debug that, we need to see more complete code so we can tell if any listeners are inside something else that causes this.

Comment: I've used a simple express app framework; on the server page the IO functions are wrapped in an app.get('/link/', function (request, response, next)). Should I post up more completed code?

Comment: Yes, we need to see more complete code to make a specific recommendation.  Also, if you want me to see your comments, please put @jfriend in front of the comment so I am notified about it.  It was luck I saw your last comment.

Comment: The issue was that the socket functions was wrapped in an express method~ Thought i'd just mention it to end this topic. Thanks for the help.